# Custom Concrete5 navigation bar

Tags: content-management-system, concrete5

I'm having a hard time finding resources on how to make a custom navigation side bar for my C5 website. I just want this navigation sidebar to display selected parts of the site. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I think we need to know more about your usage to offer assistance. Do you want something that auto-updates based on pages added to the site?  There are page properties to indicate whether to exclude a particular page from navigation.  Or would it be better to explicitly say which pages you want to be included in the navigation?  In that case, you might consider creating global blocks or stacks.  In any case, a little more info is necessary, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to display specific pages you select manually, the easiest (and free) way to do this is with the manual nav add-on:

http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/manual-nav/

This is a quick and simple way to do it if you need to have a non-complicated menu (i.e. not a nested ul or a dropdown). Plus your clients can update it themselves (if they know their way around a web admin)

Comment: this doesn't help deal with the children of a page does it? this add on seems really simple and basic